# Booking.com - credit card invalid

Tags: payment-cards, cancellations, booking.com

I made a non-refundable booking on booking.com earlier today and was told that I would be paying on the day in the hotel. However I just received an email telling me that my credit card was invalid and if I did not update my credit card in 24 hours I would lose my booking.

I have no way to get money onto this card within 24 hours as I was not anticipating having to pay anything until the day, can they still charge me the full amount if THEY cancel my booking if I don't update my details? This has quite frankly annoyed me and I am considering booking elsewhere now so I wouldn't be upset about losing the booking if I knew I wouldn't be charged.

Comment: If you don't do anything, two things will happen : your booking will be canceled, and you will not be charged.

Comment: Isn't this about the credit card info? Not about the financial part?

Comment: With a minimal effort, you'd find a lot of questions similar to yours.

Comment: Do NOT Do Nothing. Call the hotel or the booking company and explain your problems and that you are happy to pay in the hotel. You have promised to pay the hotel and they can charge you for the full stay if you do just stay away. And yes, they can charge a credit card that is not working right now, they can put on a charge to go through as soon as the card is working again.